# How to add ng-model to directive template in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i want to create a directive that i be able add ng-model to it. 
my directive is :

```
app.directive('date', function() {
return {
      restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                year:'=ngModel',
            },
            template: '' +
            '<div> ' +
            '   <div > ' +
            '       <div> ' +
            '               <input class="control" type="text" ng-model="year"/> ' +
            '   </div> ' +
            '</div>',
    require: 'ngModel',
    replace: true
   };
 });
```

when in html page i add this directive a this

```
 <date year='orderDate.year'> </date>
```

this directive ng-model name is year while i want to it be orderDate.year

Answer (score 0):

What you've done here in your isolated scope is saying that the attribute ngModel of your  directive should be called year inside your isolated scope so you should use it like that when you use your directive :

```
 <date ng-model='orderDate.year'> </date>
```

or change your scope definition to :

```
scope: {
    year:'=',
},
```

Comment: remove the require ngModel if you use the scope : { year : '='}

Comment: and your template is wrong it's missing a div closure

Answer (score 0):

You are very close. Inside your directive controller you only need to change your isolated-scope definition to:

```
scope: {
         year:'=year',
       }
```

Since the name of your attribute is the same as the name of the property in the isolated scope, the above is equal to:

```
scope: {
         year:'=',
       }
```

Working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/HrL1NdZirXBeG3pm8FiP?p=preview

More about creating scopes in directives you can find here: [Angular Docs - Directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

Comment: You will have to make sure that $scope.orderDate.year exists on your scope. If you haven't set that in your controller, it will not be known. I will add a working example to my answer.